# Airflow task succeed but returns sigterm

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I have a task in `Airflow 2.1.2` which is finishing with success status, but after that log shows a sigterm:

```
[2021-12-07 06:11:45,031] {python.py:151} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
[2021-12-07 06:11:45,224] {taskinstance.py:1204} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=DAG_ID, task_id=TASK_ID, execution_date=20211207T050000, start_date=20211207T061119, end_date=20211207T061145
[2021-12-07 06:11:45,308] {local_task_job.py:197} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to success. Terminating instance.
[2021-12-07 06:11:45,309] {taskinstance.py:1265} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
[2021-12-07 06:11:45,310] {process_utils.py:100} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 6666
[2021-12-07 06:11:45,310] {taskinstance.py:1284} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2021-12-07 06:11:45,362] {process_utils.py:66} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=6666, status='terminated', exitcode=1, started='06:11:19') (6666) terminated with exit code 1
```

As you can see the first row returns `Done`, and the previous rows of this log showed that all script worked fine and data has been inserted in the `Datawarehouse`.

In the line number 8 it shows `SIGTERM` due some external trigger mark it as success but I am sure that nobody used the `API`, or `CLI` to mark it as success neither the `UI`.
Any idea how to avoid it and why could this be happening?

I don't know if maybe increasing the `AIRFLOW_CORE_KILLED_TASK_CLEANUP_TIME` could fix it, but I would like to understand it.

Comment: Hey, we face exactly the same issue, did you find a solution for this? Thanks

Comment: Hi, @val, if i am not wrong it was related to execution_timeout for the given task.